# Getting error while registering reducers using ActionReducerMap: "not assignable to type 'ActionReducerMap<AppState, Action>"

Tags: angular, typescript, ngrx, ngrx-store

Below is simplified version of my Angular 5 application. I have a reducer, which I want to register in my root module. In *LINE A* I am getting following error:

```
ERROR in src/app/store/app.reducers.ts(7,14): error TS2322: Type '{ post: (state: State, action: Action) => void; }' is not assignable to type 'ActionReducerMap<AppState, Action>'.
  Types of property 'post' are incompatible.
    Type '(state: State, action: Action) => void' is not assignable to type 'ActionReducer<State, Action>'.
      Type 'void' is not assignable to type 'State'.
```

**app.module.ts** : Root module

```
  imports: [
    ...
    StoreModule.forRoot(reducers)
  ],
```

**store/app.reducers.ts** : inside Global store

```
import {ActionReducerMap} from "@ngrx/store";
import * as fromPost from "../postDir/store/post.reducers";

export interface AppState {
  post:fromPost.State
}
export const reducers: ActionReducerMap<AppState> = { //=======LINE A ======
  post:fromPost.postReducer
};
```

**postDir/store/post.reducers.ts** :inside local store

```
export interface State{
  query:string
  posts:Post[]
}

const initialPostState: State = {
  query:"initial",
  posts:[]
};

export function postReducer(state = initialPostState, action:postActions.PostActions){}
```

Code works fine if I replace `<AppState>` in *LINE A* with `<any>`
Did anyone else face the similar issue? I tried to google but could not find anything significant.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your error message says that property *post* has the wrong method signature. It is `(state: State, action: Action) => void`, but should be `(state: State, action: Action) => State`.

In *post.reducers.ts* your reducer needs to return the state that is passed into it like this:

```
export function postReducer(state = initialPostState, action:Action) { 
  return state;
};
```

The return type is being implicitly inferred from what you are, or in this case aren't, returning.

You could explicitly state the return type with `...): State {...` but you should still return the state.

Comment: @bygraceThanks for your response but it does return state obj in my real code. I have omitted that and a lot of other code to make this problem minimal.

Comment: @SKG can yo show the `postReducer` code? Have you tried explicitly stating its return type? The error means that the transpiler thinks that `postReducer` doesn't return anything.

Comment: I found out that the postReducer was returning incompatible type. Something like: `return [x]` instead of `return [...x]`

Answer (score 1):

please go to tsconfig.json and do strict : false

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Thanks, this works for me.

Answer (score 0):

I got a similar situation, and after a lot of time, checking my code, I found a missing property return in the switch case actions in the reducer. 
Make sure you load your previous state with spread operator `...state` so you avoid a lot of problems hard to find. In my case I returned all properties but one without first load the previous state. Got the TS2322 error and spent hours to fix and understand what happens.
Taking your code as example:

```
export function postReducer(state = initialPostState, action:postActions.PostActions){

// here you must return the state after an action
   switch (action.type){
       case postActions.ACTION_EXAMPLE:
       return {
              ...state, someProperty: action.payload  // here you load your previous state and change just that one you want

      }
      case postActions.ACTION_02_EXAMPLE:
      return {
              ...state, someProperty: action.payload  // here you load your previous state and change just that one you want

      }
     default:
     return { ...state}
   } 
}
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: In your default case, why not having `return state;` instead ?

Answer (score 0):

Answering if someone stumbles upon the same mistake I did. I had this issue using `@ngrx/entity` when I wanted to reset the state to the initial state on a specific action, I had:

`on(actions.resetState, () => adapter.getInitialState())`

when I should have had the extra properties included like

`on(actions.resetState, () => adapter.getInitialState({ foo: 'bar' }))`